# Time Series Data: Trend and Multi-Seasonality, SARIMA and TBATS predictions not working

Tags: time-series, forecasting, trend, sarimax

I have ~2.6K hours of sales data with a positive linear trend as well as daily and weekly seasonality. See [plotted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgfbB.png). I have tried to model the data using SARIMA and TBATS in python. In both cases, I cannot get the predictions to work as I intend.

For SARIMA, the in sample predictions look great, but when I try to forecast into the future, it looks completely wrong.[See here for in sample SARIMA predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RAPK.png)[See here for how poor the out of sample SARIMA predictions are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bup8.png)

For TBATS, the predicted values match the daily and weekly pattern, but is missing the positive trend, despite me forcing so that use_trend = True. [See TBATS model prediction here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKSsg.png)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and have been stuck on this for days! Any advice greatly appreciated.